# tabris.js websocket cant recive anything but a string

Tags: node.js, json, websocket, tabris-js

I am trying very hard and losing my patience with trying to send a simple array across to tabris.js

using this `ws.send(JSON.stringify(["friendArray",{data: results}]))`
i have to stringify it or it just crashes my tabris app for no reason
but when i go to `JSON.parse()` it. it keeps just giveing me an error `Unexpected token 1 in JSON at psotion 0`

I'm honestly at a loss I don't know what I could be doing wrong it could be something super simple but I'm frying my brain just trying to come up with a way to transport this simple information could someone please point me in the right direction

Comment: Check the device logs (iOS) or logcat (Android) for the exact reason of the crash.

Comment: Can you try logging out the data before passing it to `JSON.parse` to see exactly what you're getting back?

Comment: when i `console.log(message.data)` this is what i get `'["friendArray",{"data":[{"username":"Tim","uid":"twq1jiy8k34r06m5"},{"username":"dillon","uid":"1fhbe39ok323irwy"}]}]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like, I assume results is some kind of variable, you just need to put data key in double quotes.

```
JSON.stringify(["friendArray",{data: results}])
```

to -

```
JSON.stringify(["friendArray",{"data": results}])
```

Comment: well results is actually an array with objects inside

Comment: there is quite a big possibility that I am quite dumb at some times and I'm embarrassed to admit that `JSON.parse()` was doing exactly what I needed it to but I was parsing all socket messages and I forgot to convert my login true message to use json so it always just failed right when i logged in

Comment: I am still not sure what exactly you want to perform, by theway I think syntax provided above is correct as per question.

Comment: your syntax did help me but the root of the problem was me trying to parse something that was not being returned as JSON I converted all the socket events to return JSON and now it's working